# Reduction: Does polytime reduction imply Turing reduction?

Tags: computability, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

I am unsure if given $A \leqslant_p B$, does that imply that $A \leqslant_T B$.

If we can polytime reduce $A$ to $B$, that would imply there is a decider for $A$ that runs in polynomial time which can be mapped to the decider for $B$, meaning we would halt on any input that is run on the decider for $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got yourself a bit confused. If $A \le_p B$ there there is a polynomial-time computable function $f$ that maps **instances**  (not deciders) of $A$ into **instances** of $B$ such that $x \in A \iff f(x) \in B$.  This means that $x$ is a yes-instance of $A$ if and only if $f(x)$ is a yes instance of $B$.

Notice how this definition does not involve deciders halting. In fact $A$ and $B$ could even be languages for which no decider exists.

That said, if $A \le_p B$ then $A \le_T B$ since there exists a Turing machine with an oracle for $B$ that decides $A$. A possible Turing machine operates as follows on input $x$:

- It simulates a Turing machine that computes $y=f(x)$.
- It invokes the oracle for $B$ on $y$.
- If the oracle returns "yes", it accepts. Otherwise it reject.

Notice that we did not even need to use the hypothesis that $f$ can be computed *in polynomial time*.

Comment: You were right I was a bit confused on the definition of polytime reduction. Thank you for clearing this up.